# i have a problem with my php ajax chat script

Tags: php, ajax

hello i have some problems with my php ajax script

i'm using PHP/mysql

i have a field in my accounts table that will save the time for the last request from a user, i will use that to kick the idle user out of the chat. and i will make a php function that will delete all the rows that its time field more than the time limit, but where should i use this method is it okay to fire it every time a new request sent to my index.php ? i think that will make a huge load on the server,is n't it  ? do you have a better solution?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two viable solutions:

- either create a small PHP script that makes this deletion in an infinite loop (and of course sleeps for a specified amount of time before doing it again), and then start it via [PHP CLI](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php),
- or create one that makes the deletion only once, then exits, and call it from cron (if you're using a UNIXish server) or Task Scheduler (on Windows).

The second one is simpler, but its drawback is that you can't make the interval between the deletions shorter than 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to fire the deletion function just once every few requests.

Using rand() you could give it a 1 in 100 (for example) change of running the function, so that about one page request in a 100 will clean up the expired data.